# Displaying and sorting multiple queries together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to display data that combines information from multiple queries. For example:

```
@projects = @company.projects
@assignments = @company.assignments
@tasks = @company.tasks
```

How can I take these three queries and display a big table that shows projects, assignments, and tasks, all sorted together by `created_at`? The desired result will look like this:

```
7/11  Task created by company Xc for project Xp.
7/10  Project Xp created by User U.
7/09  Task created by company Yc for project Yp.
7/09  Assignment created by company Yc for project Yp.
7/08  Project Yp created by user U.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SQL `UNION` query for that if you want to do more complex stuff like getting the newest x entries only or for pagination.

If you know the data is very few, you can collect the results in an array and sort by `created_at`

```
@events = @projects.to_a + @assignments.to_a + @tasks.to_a
@events.sort_by! { |e| e.created_at }
```

Comment: @events.sort_by!(&:created_at)

Comment: Yes, that shorthand is also good. But I believe the expanded form is easier to understand.